# Create a GRUB2 installer in a pendrive

Tags: grub2

I need to create a grub2 installer in a usb. I need step by step to do that in console mode

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Are you running LInux or have a working live installer?

Comment: As you're a reputation 22 user: If the below answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install GRUB2 on USB from Ubuntu:

**Note**: This Grub2 USB Flash Drive Install tutorial assumes you will be running from an Ubuntu Live CD to create your Grub2 enabled Flash Drive. It may or may not work from another Linux operating environment.

Grub2 USB Install From Ubuntu Live CD Essentials:

- Ubuntu Live CD --
- A PC that can boot from USB/CD
- 1GB or larger USB Flash Drive

Grub2 USB Flash Drive Install using the Ubuntu Live CD:

1. Boot from your Live Ubuntu Linux CD
2. Once booted, insert your USB Flash Drive
3. Open a terminal and type `sudo su`
4. Type `fdisk --list` (and note which device is your USB)
5. Type `mkdir /mnt/USB && mount /dev/XdY1 /mnt/USB` (replacing `X` and `Y` with your actual USB device)
6. Type `grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/XdY` (replacing `X` and `Y` with your actual USB device)
7. Type `cd /mnt/USB/boot/grub`
8. Type `wget pendrivelinux.com/downloads/grub.cfg`
9. Type `df` (and locate where the cdrom is mounted E.G. `/dev/sr0`)
10. Type `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=/mnt/USB/ubuntu.iso` (replacing `sr0` with the device found in step 9)
11. Remove your Live CD and reboot your PC, setting your BIOS or Boot Menu to boot from the USB device

Reference [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-ubuntu-linux/)